# What is the time complexity of computing the Nth fibonacci number with dynamic programming?

Tags: algorithm, recursion, time-complexity, dynamic-programming, fibonacci

I recently solved the time complexity for the Fibonacci algorithm using recursion. This is a standard solution with a time complexity of O(2^n). I was wondering if you were to use a DP algorithm, which saves fibonacci numbers that have already been calculated, what would the time complexity be? Thanks!

Comment: I don't think it's a standard result that Fibonacci runs in O(2^n). It runs in Theta(phi^n), where phi is the golden ratio. O(2^n) is theoretically correct (because it's an upper bound), but usually a stated big O class is assumed to be a tight bound.

Answer (score 0):

It is a simple loop over n numbers so it is O(n).
Edit: i should be more specific.

```
long fib(long n){
    long *f=new long[n+1];
    f[0]=0;
    f[1]=1;
    for(int i=2;i<=n;++i)
       f[i]=f[i-1]+f[i-2];
    long res=f[n];
    delete[] f;
    return res;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

O(n).

Basically, the first time you call `fib(n)`, it will take O(n). The second time, as the answer will be stored in an array, it will take O(1).

The dynamic programming algorithm is something like this:

```
int f[100];

int fib(int n){
    if( f[n] != 0 ) return f[n];
    f[n] = fib( n - 1 ) + fib( n - 2 );
    return f[n];
}
```

So the first time, it will last O(n) time, just like the common algorithm, but in practice, it will run 2 times faster, because then you call `fib(n - 1)`, after it ends, it will have stored `f[n - 1]`, `f[n - 2]`, `f[n -  3]`, ..., up to `f[1]`, so it should help all the other `fib` calls to end in O(1).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following matrix multiplication method:

[image]

You can optimize the computation and do it in `O(log(n))`:

```py
# Fibonacci Series using  
# Optimized Method 
  
# function that returns nth  
# Fibonacci number  
def fib(n): 
      
    F = [[1, 1], 
         [1, 0]] 
    if (n == 0): 
        return 0
    power(F, n - 1) 
          
    return F[0][0] 
      
def multiply(F, M): 
      
    x = (F[0][0] * M[0][0] + 
         F[0][1] * M[1][0]) 
    y = (F[0][0] * M[0][1] + 
         F[0][1] * M[1][1]) 
    z = (F[1][0] * M[0][0] + 
         F[1][1] * M[1][0]) 
    w = (F[1][0] * M[0][1] + 
         F[1][1] * M[1][1]) 
      
    F[0][0] = x 
    F[0][1] = y 
    F[1][0] = z 
    F[1][1] = w 
          
# Optimized version of 
# power() in method 4  
def power(F, n): 
  
    if( n == 0 or n == 1): 
        return; 
    M = [[1, 1], 
         [1, 0]]; 
          
    power(F, n // 2) 
    multiply(F, F) 
          
    if (n % 2 != 0): 
        multiply(F, M) 
      
# Driver Code 
if __name__ == "__main__": 
    n = 9
    print(fib(n)) 
  
# This code is contributed  
# by ChitraNayal
```

See the source [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/program-for-nth-fibonacci-number/) (more generalization [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/matrix-exponentiation/)).